How can I make the back button in my Android app return to the previous app instead of previous activities in my own app?
I have an Android app with two activities. The Launcher activity is a Kotlin AndroidX activity and the other is a game based on NativeActivity. The launcher activity is always displayed first and after some user interaction it calls the game activity.
If you press the back button in the game activity it destroys the game activity and returns to the launcher activity. But that means when they launch the game activity again it has to reload all assets and that takes a long time - not a good user experience.
The behavior I'd like to see is pressing the back button in the game activity does the same thing as pressing the back button in the launcher activity (i.e. it goes back to the previous app or whatever). In other words once the game activity is displayed I don't want the launch activity to be seen again (for that run of the app).
In essence I'd like the back button to not destroy my game activity so I don't have to rebuild it again when the user comes back to it. And when they return to my app I want it to display the game activity the user was viewing when they pressed the back button, not the launcher.

If you don't want an Activity to be on the backstack, make sure to call finish() in it after launching the next activity.  That will end it and remove it from the stack

Thanks Gabe! That's very good to know. But the second part of the problem is the OS calls DESTROY on the game activity when the back button is pressed. Is there a way to prevent it from doing that?
If I use either of the other two nav bar buttons it doesn't destroy my game activity. That's what I need for the back button too.

Pressing back by default calls finish().  That's what finish does, and the expected behavior of back is to end the current activity.  You could try overriding onBackPressed to do something else, but there's no way to go back to the last app-  that's based on the backstack, and to move back the backstack you need to exit the top of it (the current activity) via finish.  You might be able to launch the home activity to go to the home screen.

Pressing back by default calls finish().  No, not anymore on modern Android devices. Not on 12+ i think. @Gabe Sechan. The activity just vanishes but comes back in the same state when launched again.

blackcaps that's not what I'm seeing. Even on Android 14 it calls destroy on the activity when back is touched.

The final answer has two steps. Per Gabe's answer the Launch activity needs to call finish() after launching the Game activity.
private fun startGame() {
    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, GameActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}

The second step is in GameActivity where we prevent the activity from being destroyed when the back button is pressed.
override fun onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true)
}

This combination is what worked for me.
